# Laravel docker API routes not working, but web routes work

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have developed a RESTful API in Laravel that is consumed by a ReactJS client side.
They work fine.
I dockerized the Laravel backend and the React frontend.
The web routes in Laravel work fine (so localhost:8000), however, the API routes do not work ...
Does anyone have an idea where the problem might be? I doubt there is something wrong with my dockerfiles and docker compose because the Laravel web routes work and the frontend works ... it's only the laravel api routes that do not work ...

This is my yml file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./clientside
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./clientside:/app/clientside
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app

  backend:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: ./coolserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: mynewserver
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD:
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./coolserver:/app/coolserver
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app

  db:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mynewserver
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my dockerfile for the backend

```
FROM php:7.3
 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git 
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring pdo_mysql 

WORKDIR /app/coolserver
COPY . .
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 
EXPOSE 8000
```

and finally this is my react dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine 
WORKDIR /app/clientside
COPY . . 
RUN npm install 
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it; I should have set the DB_HOST in my env file to the name of the service that will run the database (in this case db).
The default configuration of DB_HOST causes the connection to the db service to be refused.